# Working with defaults-group-suffix in MariaDB/MySQL if it's empty

Tags: configuration, mariadb

According to the documentation it's possible to add the parameter `--defaults-group-suffix` to a mysql command, for it to "In addition to the default option groups, also read option groups with the given suffix".

So in case I use:
`--defaults-group-suffix=.sample`

A mariadb-Server started with this option will read both, the following blocks:

```
[mariadbd]
…
[mariadbd.sample]
…
```

So I can put options which should apply to the specific instance to the second block.

My question is: Is there a way to add an option group, which is only evaluated, when the parameter `--defaults-group-suffix` is not provided, in other words empty?

The default block `[mariadbd]` obviously can't be used, since it is read by all instances with a defined suffix.

---

Additional question, since I can't find it in the documentation: If one option is specified multiple times in one (or more) configuration files: Is it the first, or the last match, that applies?

Answer (score 1):

According to the stackoverflow guidelines, next time please only ask one question per posting.

1st question: No, it is not possible - the suffix option is an additional option, there are no conditions which check suffix and other options.

2nd question: If multiple configuration files with same options but different values are used, the option/value from last read configuration file will be used. Check the read order of configuration files by executing

```
mysqld --help --verbose | grep -C1 "Default options"
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```